# Filtering by condition in Python dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataset

I'm struggling with a sorting operation of a stata file in Phyton3: I was asked to keep only the households without kids out of a dataset/table:

I used a filtering condition to filter these rows out of the table:

```
filtering_condition = df["kids"] > 0

df_nokids = df.loc[filtering_condition,"kids"]
```

This, however, gives me an unknown error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
1944             try:
-> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item     (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'kids'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-321-e72cd8a67065> in <module>()
      1 #keep only the households without kids and use this dataset for the   rest of the assignment
----> 2 filtering_condition = df["kids"] > 0
      3 df_nokids = df.loc[filtering_condition,"kids"]

/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in  __getitem__(self, key)
   1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1996         else:
-> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1998 
   1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in  _getitem_column(self, key)
   2002         # get column
   2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2005 
   2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py    in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1348         res = cache.get(item)
   1349         if res is None:
-> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
   1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1352             cache[item] = res

/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py     in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3288 
   3289             if not isnull(item):
-> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3291             else:
   3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))   [isnull(self.items)]

 /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py    in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:
-> 1947                 return     self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   1948 
   1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method,    tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'kids'
```

Any explanations of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Datafile:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a runnable code? The stacktrace says Keyerror which means 'kids' is not present in the original data. It would help if you can post the complete code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess you might be right and I forgot a step before as this is the complete code I used. I only first read the stata file by:     pd.read_stata("data/alcohol.dta")

The table looks like this:
 , adults, kids, income, consume
0 2 2 758 1
1 2 3 1785 1
2 3 0 1200 1
3 1 0 545 1
4 4 1 547 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
df_kids = df[df['kids']>0]
```

This selects the rows where the 'kids' column is not zero.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Putting in this code however gives a similar error code.
Perhaps the column is maybe not properly coded as kids?
Or do I maybe have to do something with numpy arrays?

Comment: Possibly your data types are not correct (are not integers). Verify this using print (df.dtypes). If it does not say something like int64 for 'kids', you will have to convert the datatype to integer first. Use df['kids'] = pd.to_numeric(df['kids'])
 for that.

Comment: You are correct: It says both x and y are floats.
I now see this reflects to an assignment I had to do inbetween, getting describtive statistics of the data.
I used simply: df.describe() and now see these describtive statistics don;t correspont to the Kids data
I guess the describtive code is wrong as well?

Comment: Well, float64 would have no problem with my code given above. However, user567 is correctly pointing out that you have a Key Error. That means your columns are probably not named the way you expect them to. Can you print your df (or if it's long, df.head() ), please. (best to add it to your question)

Comment: well, actually it is not a df. but a pd. Would that make any difference?

Comment: I managed to transform my pd into df: at least the describtive table is correct now. I will try to do the kids > 0 now

Comment: If you write only these two lines: df = pd.read_stata("data/alcohol.dta") and then df_kids = df[df['kids']>0], what happens? Note, pd is short for pandas, it's not a data type. Please read some basic pandas tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help: my code now works. So good to know to first transform the pd into a df

Comment: Ok, that's great. Could you mark the answer as accepted then, so that we know the issue is resolved.